# Python script to set another layer inactive & select point by outside of boundary line?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, select-by-expression

I have two layers, "IDN_ALL" as Polygon and "Point_Link" as point.
"Point_Link" is the active layer. I want to select point data outside polygon data.

Code:

```
Layer1 = iface.activeLayer()
Layer2 = ??
layer1.selectByexpression("\"?..")
```

How can I select points outside polygons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the options below. This will select all features in your point layer which lie *outside* of your polygon layer.

**Note:** Both layers should be in the same Coordinate Reference System, and in both cases make absolutely sure that the layer names match yours and are spelt correctly e.g. 'Point_Link' for the point layer and 'IDN_ALL' for the polygon layer.

Option 1- use processing algorithm 'Select By Location'

```py
project = QgsProject().instance()
Layer1 = project.mapLayersByName('Point_Link')[0]
Layer2 = project.mapLayersByName('IDN_ALL')[0]
processing.run("qgis:selectbylocation", {'INPUT':Layer1,'PREDICATE':[6],'INTERSECT':Layer2,'METHOD':0})
Layer1.invertSelection()
```

Option 2- This approach avoids the use of processing, but will produce the same result.

```py
project = QgsProject().instance()
Layer1 = project.mapLayersByName('Point_Link')[0]
Layer2 = project.mapLayersByName('IDN_ALL')[0]
index = QgsSpatialIndex(Layer1.getFeatures())
pntFts = [f for f in Layer1.getFeatures()]

pts2select = []
for f in Layer2.getFeatures():
    candidateIds = index.intersects(f.geometry().boundingBox())
    candidateFts = [f for f in pntFts if f.id() in candidateIds]
    for p in candidateFts:
        if p.geometry().within(f.geometry()):
            pts2select.append(p.id())
    
Layer1.selectByIds(pts2select)
Layer1.invertSelection()
```

Comment: thankyou.
I try to run and find this error report
Traceback (most recent call last):

  ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 181, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.

Comment: Double check that the layer names exactly match yours. Also, which version of QGIS do you use?

Comment: i used QGIS 3.10

Comment: @adham CMajid, it works fine for me in both 3.10 and 3.14. I can't say why it doesn't work for you. I have added another option to my answer which does not rely on processing. Please try that instead. If your layers are very large e.g. thousands of features, let me know and I will edit the code.

Comment: yes, my data is very large

Comment: @adham CMajid, try option 2 in my edited answer.

Comment: that's great. running successfully. 
thankyou Ben

Comment: Hi Ben. I need your help to select in the same query but additional cases by specific attribute.

Comment: @adham CMajid, since this question has already been asked and solved, if you have additional requirements I would suggest asking a new question and including a link to this previous question for reference and background information.